WPF Vertical Scrollbar in Combox
I would like to put a vertical scrollbar in a combobox list and set the size height of the list
but it does not work - here is my code - with the scroll viewer in it - the list even not open
Any ideas?`
        <Grid>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" 
                  Background="#EE2222"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="▼" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>

            </ToggleButton>

            <Popup x:Name="Popup" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom">

                <Border Background="#000000"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">


                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>

                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>`


ComboBox Styles and Templates
